# Two sheeted disconnected cover of a connected topological space has exactly two components

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\tilde{X}$ be a two-sheeted cover of a connected topological space X. If $\tilde{X}$ is disconnected then this has exactly two components. Further each component is homeomorphic to X by the covering projection. Can anyone give the argument for this statement ?

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: I was just applying the definition of covering space. But I don't have any clue, how this comes from the definition ?.

Comment: If you would have a section $s:X \to \bar X$, you would be happy since you know the projection is a local homeomorphism. This is easy when you consider path-connected spaces, but gives you the right idea.

Comment: Hint: Verify that the restriction of a covering map to a connected component is still a covering map to its image.

Comment: Sorry, here what is mean by section?

Comment: studiosus ! thanks, but how this followes from this hint?

Comment: Try to think a bit more: This is a very good problem to try on your own. what would you call a covering map which has multiplicity (degree) 1?